# How to avoid 'ambigous redirect' when executing command over ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, freebsd, csh

I'm trying to execute a script on a remote server via ssh.

the command should go to the background and continue to run after logout.
The result of the command should be redireced to out.log on the remote site.

the ssh process should exit without waiting for the command

The remote shell is csh

I tried various versions (quoting, braces...) of the following line

```
ssh target.host "nohup csh longrunning.sh > out.log 2>&1 &; exit"
```

Either my attempts don't do anything on the remote site or I get ambiguous redirect, because of the multiple ampersands.

The remote site is a minimal FreeBSD system, with no tools like `screen` installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aren't you just looking for

```
ssh target.host "nohup csh longrunning.sh >& out.log &; exit"
```

It seems to be the correct syntax for csh for what you are trying to achieve.

The syntax you are using is incompatible with csh as its syntax is not Bourne shell compatible.